# Open Graph Object Debugger Sees Tag (og:image) that is NOT There ...with a Wordpress Site

Tags: wordpress, debugging, tags, metadata

I added metadata to the header.php file for a Wordpress site I am working on. I wanted to be sure about what shows up in Facebook when the URL is dropped in there.

I created an image with the company logo and put it in the image tag like this: |meta property="og:image" content="https://www.nextlevelcbd.net/nextlevelcbd-logo-facebook.png"| ...it is simply in the root folder of the site.

The debugger says that it also sees this tag: |meta property="og:image" content="https://s0.wp.com/i/blank.jpg"| ...That tag is not in the header.php file at all.

There is, indeed, a small, square, white image, (blank.jpg), at that location. That is just the strangest thing. I would never have used that image for anything. You can see mine here: https://www.nextlevelcbd.net/nextlevelcbd-logo-facebook.png  ...and the debugger sees both, but will not use mine.

Does anyone have any idea how this can be and how to fix it?

This is the debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/
This is the site URL: http://nextlevelcbd.net/

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by adding og tags in `function.php` file we phase same problem and we fix it by

> adding this code

```
add_action('wp_head', 'fc_opengraph');
function fc_opengraph() {

  if( is_single() || is_page() ) {

$post_id = get_queried_object_id();

$url = get_permalink($post_id);
$title = get_the_title($post_id);
$site_name = get_bloginfo('name');

$description = wp_trim_words( get_post_field('post_content', $post_id), 25 );

$image = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post_id);
if( !empty( get_post_meta($post_id, 'og_image', true) ) ) $image = get_post_meta($post_id, 'og_image', true);

$locale = get_locale();

echo '<meta property="og:locale" content="' . esc_attr($locale) . '" />';
echo '<meta property="og:type" content="article" />';
echo '<meta property="og:title" content="' . esc_attr($title) . ' | ' . esc_attr($site_name) . '" />';
echo '<meta property="og:description" content="' . esc_attr($description) . '" />';
echo '<meta property="og:url" content="' . esc_url($url) . '" />';
echo '<meta property="og:site_name" content="' . esc_attr($site_name) . '" />';

if($image) echo '<meta property="og:image" content="' . esc_url($image) . '" />';

// Twitter Card
echo '<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" />';
echo '<meta name="twitter:site" content="@francecarlucci" />';
echo '<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@francecarlucci" />';

  }

}
```

you can also check your site status of og tags on https://socialdebug.com/